# i can decompile this encoded dll file?

Tags: dll

i want decompile this dll file
https://mega.nz/file/MLwjEQxB#kSNO_lked5EtlJQK8UD19AdHC8ig0rb8CFBSmUjL4J4

Comment: Note that [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) isn't a code writing (or any other type of) service. Please post **what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems**. 
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Comment: How did you get this file? What is it supposed to contain? Please provide more details.